# reactjs pass data from span tag to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wonder if there is a way to pass data from `span` tag in `Data.js` to `RenderLetter.js`. `getInput` is a text from input that I need to use along with `sendLetter`.
This is an example:
`Data.js`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import RenderLetter from "./RenderLetter";

function Data({ randomData, getInput }) {
  const [dummyData, setDummyData] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      {dummyData ? (
        <div>
          {dummyData.split("").map((letter, i) => {
            let color;
            if (i < getInput.length) {
              color = letter === getInput[i] ? "green" : "red";
            }

            return (
              <>
                {/*------ I need to pass this letter data to RenderLetter component ------*/}
                <span key={i} style={{ background: color }} sendLetter={letter}>
                  {letter}
                </span>
              </>
            );
          })}

          <RenderLetter sendInput={getInput} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>Loading</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Data;
```

`RenderLetter.js`

```
import React from 'react'

function RenderLetter({ sendInput, sendLetter }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(sendInput)}
            {console.log(sendLetter)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default RenderLetter;
```

Comment: You can many different `<span>`'s since you're mapping over an array from a split string, yet you only have a single `<RenderLetter>` tag. Which value would you expect to pass? Your `RenderLetter` also seems to expect a `sendLetter` which isn't present in the `<RenderLetter sendInput={getInput} />` element.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs That is right. Since I have many `<span>` it acts a bit weird when I render it. I intentionally didn't do `<RenderLetter sendInput={getInput} sendLetter={letter} />` because letter is not defined here. I think I found another approach by getting `dummyData` and pretty much loop and do similar thing in the other component.